# Apache2 Server Won't Start

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I am new to servers and Apache in general. I am trying to set up an apache 2.4 server to learn php and mysql on. I followed the apache documentation for setup as well as the guide here http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Now when I run 'service apache2 start' I get this error:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * 
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

From here I did 'desktop@desktop-pc:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80'
and the result is below:

```
[sudo] password for desktop: 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19493/httpd     
desktop@desktop-pc:~$
```

To me this looks like nothing is using port 80. I simply do not understand ports or this error too well. I have scoured the Internet, but I either do not understand the solution or cannot implement it.

I thank you for any help you can provide. If more information is needed I will provide it to the best of my abilities. Also I am on Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `sudo service apache2 status`.

Comment: Formatted code and messages.

Answer (score 1):

First try to start Apache on an other port. If it didn't work, your antivirus programm is maybe blocking the Apache-service.

Comment: Thank you. This was not the issue but I was able to fix this problem. Leading me to yet more problems.